# 413 Request Entity Too Large nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: uploads, nginx

This message occurs whenever I attempt to upload a file greater than 2M in wordpress. I have made the follow changes in order to increase the allowed file upload sizes:

In nginx.conf, I added

```
client_max_body_size 200M;
```

In php.ini, I modified

```
upload_max_filesize = 200M
max_file_uploads = 20
Post_max_size = 256M
```

In wp-config.php, I added

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize' , '200M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size' , '256M' );
@ini_set( 'memory_limit' , 256M' );
```

Even with these parameters set in the three configuration files I am still getting the message
**413 Request Entity Too Large nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)**

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you reload Nginx? This isn't something that can be fixed from the WordPress/PHP end, it's an Nginx issue. It may be more appropriate to ask this on serverfault or superuser

Comment: I did a quick google and the first result gave the `client_max_body_size` based solution, I can only assume you did not apply the change by reloading or restarting Nginx, and that it is still running from before you made the change. This does confirm though that this issue has nothing to do with WP though

Comment: See if you haven't stepped onto [client_max_body_size inheritance](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/nginx-client_max_body_size-inheritance) pitfall.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**

In addition to increasing the maximum size in nginx.conf, php.ini and wp-conf.php files, it was necessary to raise the limit in the nginx server block for the site. I increased the default value of

```
client_max_body_size 2M;     to
client_max_body_size 200M;
```

and now all uploads go smoothly and quickly.

Hopefully, someone can tell me why I had to modify 4 separate files in order to raise the size limit when uploading files.

Answer (score 0):

### FOR MORE EXPLANATION

You can add **client_max_body_size** or midify it in **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** in 3 blocks

**HTTP block** : which affects all server blocks (virtual hosts)

```
http {
    ...
    # increase the limit
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

**SERVER block** : which affects a particular site/app.

```
server {
    ...
    # increase the limit
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

**LOCATION block** : which affects a particular directory (uploads) under a site/app.

```
location {
    ...
    # increase the limit
    client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

After having edited the configuration file you must restart your nginx server

```
$ systemctl restart nginx
```